# Minor but important changes should be allowed

Tags: discussion, answers

I was reading [this answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/44081/2289) and found that though the answer is quite good it will be even better if some grammatical and spelling mistakes can be removed. So I tried editing it and in all the places converted 'you' to 'your' because 'you father' doesn't make sense to me. Other than that their were 1-2 places where I corrected grammatical mistakes.

But when I tried posting it, I got error like "edits must be atleast 10 chars long", Don't you think that some important edits even if they are small should be allowed ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, they should. That's why people with over 2,000 reputation can make those corrections even if they are only a single character.

The reason that privilege is restricted is because suggested edits need to be approved by other people, increasing the amount of community time it takes to make each one.

Usually if there are enough errors to merit a suggested edit, you can find something else small to improve as well (perhaps the title, or a misspelling somewhere), and then there is no problem, but in the meantime I understand it can be frustrating.

Edits are really appreciated, and thank you for making them. Soon enough you'll be at 2k reputation and be able to make those minor edits without review.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please correct the answer  I pointed. It is still showing 'you father' instead of 'your father'.

Comment: @amit done. I fixed a couple other things so it ended up over 10 characters, [take a look](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/44081/revisions) if you want to see what I mean.